# In jest I can't access to my exported module

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, nodes, ts-jest

> **For example, I can't access to this module, why ?**

```
let nodeCacheClient;

module.exports = {
    initNodeCache: () => {
        const NodeCache = require("node-cache");
        nodeCacheClient = new NodeCache();
        return nodeCacheClient;
    },
    insertToCacheWithTtl: (key, obj, ttl) => {
        return nodeCacheClient.set(key, obj, ttl);
    },
    getCache: (key) => {
        return nodeCacheClient.get(key);
    },
    deleteKey: (key) => {
        return nodeCacheClient.del(key);
    },
};
```

> > when I run this test I get this : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Error**

```
test("login a user", async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axiosInstance.post("users/login", {
                email: "test@gmail.com",
                password: "144847120",
                otpCode: getCacheClient.getCache("test@gmail.com")
            });
            console.log(response.data);
            expect(response.data.status).toBe("success");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error + " Error");
            expect(error);
        }
 });
```

Comment: your test does not contain other things other than what you showed us?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA The real question is why my exported module can't access to jest tests ?

Comment: Your question is " why your exported module can't access to jest tests" OR "Why your exported module can't be accessed from jest tests " ?

Answer (score 0):

It’s totally normal!

Actually you got access to your module, and the error is coming into your module where the “**nodeCacheClient**” is undefined since it was not defined!

Your error is coming from your “**getCache()**” function, in this syntax:

```
return nodeCacheClient.get(key);
```

Where in your test you didnt call for the “**initNodeCache()**” method which will do

```
nodeCacheClient = new NodeCache();
```

So, for your test scope, the **nodeCacheClient** is **undefined**, and that’s why

```
nodeCacheClient.get(key);
```

Will return the

```
typeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Error
```

Comment: I do this in server.js when server is ready for listening app.listen(PORT, () => {
    getCacheClient.initNodeCache()
    console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`);
})

Comment: Via Postman, everything is doing fine :(

Comment: Postman, or local environment is not like the test environment !

Comment: To understand what im saying, put a console.log(nodeCacheClient) into your getCache() function.
In Postman, this will log some value, but in test this will return "undefined"
So in your test you should make sure that the nodeCacheClient has a value.

Comment: exactly, but the node-cache is created again and all keys and values are cleared

Comment: Your question was "Why?"
Now you asked "How?", You should create a function wich will return the nodeCacheClient. In this function check if it is not instancied. Then export this function, and then in your test you should MOCK this function....

Comment: Even now I add this getCacheClient.initNodeCache(); to my test but not working :(.

Comment: I do it that way and if any luck I replay asap, thanks man